# How to redirect only child pages/subdirectories in Apache?

Tags: apache, redirect

I want all URL's "below" example.com/stuff/ to redirect to https://www.other-website.com. For example, example.com/stuff/chair or example.com/stuff/table will both redirect but example.com/stuff/ will not.

Comment: I have provided the working example. If it solves your problem do let the other SO user knows by accepting it through clicking the right button near the answer. In case you are struggling with the solution,leave me a comment.

Comment: I don't know if your solutions works, I found a solution and answered my own question but it got deleted due to no explanation. This was my solution:
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/stuff/(.+) https://www.other-website.com`

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache **mod_rewrite** module for the same.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/stuff$

RewriteRule .? - [S=1]

RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.other-website.com  [R,L]
```